# How do you prevent search results from showing when the search term is empty in Algolia?

Tags: algolia

I followed their [tutorial](https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/search-ui/instant-search/build-an-instant-search-results-page/instantsearchjs/), but it always shows pages of search results, even when the page is first loaded and the contents of the search box is empty. I tried adding `queryHook` and only search when the term is not blank, but it still shows search results when you load the page. In fact, the `queryHook` is not even called upon first load. It's only called when you type in the search box. How do you hide the search results *unless* the user starts typing?

https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v2/widgets/searchBox.html#usage

This works, but I don't think it's the right way because it still does a search on an empty text box. Also when you reset the search terms by clicking the `X` on the right, then it doesn't hide the results (because it doesn't call `queryHook`).

```
    <main id="results" class="collapse">
        <div id="hits"></div>
        <div id="pagination"></div>
    </main>

  # CoffeeScript
  search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
      container: '#search-input',
      queryHook: (term, searchFunction) ->
        console.log "term = #{term}"
        if term
          $('#results').show()
        else
          $('#results').hide()
        searchFunction(term)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Helper.js library](https://community.algolia.com/algoliasearch-helper-js/) which is already part of InstantSearch.  In your case, check for the query length when you instantiate your search:

```
var search = instantsearch({
    // other search parameters
    searchFunction: function(helper) {
    if (helper.state.query.length === 0) {
        return; // do not trigger search
    }

    helper.search(); // trigger search
  }
});
```

Comment: OK that works when the page first loads, but the `X - Clear the Search Results` still doesn't work, and when you delete the search term, the results are still listed. You would think that the initial state would be no results by default.

Comment: I used a combination of my solution and your solution to hide the results when the user manually erases the search term, but the X clear button still doesn't work.